# Mesomeric form and organic reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm looking to find all the mesomeric form of the compound A. I don't know how to take it because there is triple bond. I think one bond of the double bond of ceton can go on the oxygen, but after that i'm quite lost.
Also, i want to find what is the product(B) after the reaction with NaH and also what this compound B can product (D) after the reaction with compound C.

[image: Text]

Thank you for your time and your help

Comment: $\ce{A}$ is methyl propynoate. It is not a ketone.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's an ester.

Comment: And you don't really need to think about mesomeric structures in this q.

Comment: the most acidic proton is on the end of the triple bond

Comment: If the bromide has the apparent relative stereochemistry (3S*,4R*)-3-bromo-4-methylhexane and given the branching and the presence of a secondary bromide, elimination to (Z)-3-methylhex-3-ene is a/the product D.

Answer (score 1):

**First stage**

At the first stage of the reaction scheme, sodium acetylide **B** of a terminal alkyne **A** is obtained:
[image]

**Second stage**

The second stage of the reaction scheme is alkynylation of **C** via the SN2 mechanism with the inversion of configuration from *(S)* to *(R)* (see the image):
[image]